# Rails: Hide form field when value is popuated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have this form.  When the object has a value for gender, I want to change the gender field to a hidden field, so the user does not need to see it. What is the best way to do this?

```
    <%= form_for( object ,:html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %> 
       <div class="form-group row">
          <%= f.label(:first_name, :class => "control-label col-xs-4 input-lg") %>

            <div class="form-inline col-xs-8">
                <div class="">
                    <%= f.text_field( :first_name,{class: "form-control input-lg"}) %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <%= f.label(:last_name, :class => "control-label col-xs-4 input-lg") %>

            <div class="form-inline col-xs-8">
                <div class="">
                    <%= f.text_field( :last_name,{class: "form-control input-lg"}) %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
          <%= f.label(:gender, :class => "control-label col-xs-4 input-lg") %>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
            <%= f.select( :gender, Dropdown.gender,{:prompt =>"Please Choose"},{class: "form-control input-lg"}) %>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
               <%= f.submit object.submit_button_name, {class: 'btn btn-lg'} %>
            </div>

    <% end %>
```

Comment: What does your controller indicate should be done after save? I'm betting that's where the issue is. You should have a redirect_to there after save.

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with the controller, just the view, but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use an if statement to render different field types based on whether gender is set or not:

```
  <% if object.gender %>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:gender)
  <% else %>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label(:gender, :class => "control-label col-xs-4 input-lg") %>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <%= f.select( :gender, Dropdown.gender,{:prompt =>"Please Choose"},{class: "form-control input-lg"}) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Pretty sure this would display the HTML since its not part of the if statement. How would I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hidding it, it's better to not rendering it. Try it like this:

```
<% unless object.gender != nil %>
<div class="form-group row">
  <%= f.label(:gender, :class => "control-label col-xs-4 input-lg") %>
<div class="col-xs-8">
  <%= f.select( :gender, Dropdown.gender,{:prompt =>"Please Choose"},{class: "form-control input-lg"}) %>
 </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Doesn't the above code also show the HTML since it's not part of the ruby (<%= %>?

Comment: It's inside the ruby statement. If the statement returns true it will render the gender part in HTML. If the statement returns false, it won't render it, so also not in HTML.

Comment: If I don't render it with a hidden, the values get lost and I get validation errors. Used the if else statement. but good recommendation. thank you

Comment: Ahh yes, you're right. Then I don't see an other option then the hidden field, but it will be there in the source code yes.